# javascript widget withe php build 2d array

Tags: php, javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a widget, where user can do some calculations without leaving the widget.

I think it can only be done in Javascript, not PHP submit forms, which will refresh and redirect the page inside the widget.

I generate a 2d array from sql statements in PHP and send to the Javascript, and Javascript builds the form content.

Say, I build the js 2d array a_array=[[q1,w1,e1],[q2,w2,e2],...,[qx,wx,ex]];

How can I build a drop-down box html content from the javascript?

```
<select ...>
<option value=w1>q1 -e1</option>
<option value=w2>q2 -e2</option>
...
<option value=wx>qx -ex</option>
</select>
```

in my php script, I am trying to write fm to the javascript, but not working.

```
    $fm .= '<select name=\"f\" style=\"width:90%\" onchange=\"this.form.submit()\">';
    $fm .= 'for (i=0; i<m_array.length; i++){';
    $fm .= '\"<option value=\"+m_array[i][0]+\"';
    $fm .= 'if (m_array[i][0] == f )';
    $fm .= ' selected=\'selected\'';
    $fm .= '\">+m_array[$i][0]+\" - \"+m_array[i][2]+\"</option>\"';
    $fm .= '}';
    $fm .= '</select>';
    ....
    echo 'document.write("'.$fm.'")';
```

Comment: i suck. i don't know how to build the drop-down inside the php file for the javascript

Comment: if you don't know something it doesn't mean that you suck, but you should start by reading a tutorial on arrays in this case.. people around here don't use to do the work for others.. you should come here with issues in some development you made..

Comment: I tried to put those into javascript from php, but it doesn't work. anything wrong with these codes? $fm .= '<select name=\"f\" style=\"width:90%\" onchange=\"this.form.submit()\">';
 $fm .= 'for (i=0; i<m_array.length; i++){';
 $fm .= '\"<option value=\"+m_array[i][0]+\"';
 $fm .= 'if (m_array[i][0] == f )';
 $fm .= ' selected=\'selected\'';
 $fm .= '\">+m_array[$i][0]+\" - \"+m_array[i][2]+\"</option>\"';
 $fm .= '}';
 $fm .= '</select>';

Comment: please update your question with this sample.. it's very hard to read this way..

Answer (score 0):

You generally create elements in JavaScript using the DOM method document.createElement(tagName) and append with el.appendChild(c). You can also create node trees using innerHTML, as in

```
el.innerHTML = '<p>aaa</p>'
```

So, for what you are doing, the following may be reasonable:

```
// Assume `options` is a JavaScript Array as you described, and `form`
// is a <form> element, as in document.forms.the_form_name.
var sel = document.createElement('select'),
    el;
for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
    el = document.createElement('option');
    el.value = options[i][1];
    el.textContent = options[i][0] + ' -' + options[i][2];
    sel.appendChild(el);
}
form.appendChild(sel);
```

Comment: the array is m_array, and i was just trying to build a html drop-down box content from js

Comment: Well then, of course you will change `options` above to `m_array`. If `m_array` is actually `$m_array`, you can easily insert it in your JavaScript code, as `var m_array = <?php echo json_encode($m_array); ?>;` All things being equal, your users will almost certainly prefer the dropdown to be built on the PHP side, unless the element is to be generated and inserted on the page dynamically, in which case building in JavaScript is preferable to getting HTML via Ajax (because you save the HTTP request).